# How to parse XML to a column(field) of SharePoint List on a new/edit form via CEWP

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices, cewp

**Problem description:**

I want to parse the XML to fill up some columns(single line text) on the new/edit form automatically after clicking the load button.

**Background:**

The XML is from an external resource, not from my or any other SP site/list/item.
Currently, the user has to check the web page of the external resource and copy/paste the info they need to the new/edit form when creating new item or updating an existing item.
The external website provides an API which allows me to get the info in XML format, so I'm trying to make this task easier for the users of my site.
The idea is they only have to input a 6 digits number which is used to identify the external resource, then the needed info can be put into the new/edit form so they only have to press save to submit/update the item in this list.

**What I've done so far:**

I'm just a SharePoint user, not a developer and also not familiar with JS.
Luckily I could find some articles as instruction and shared codes for me to implement some features e.g. cascading dropdown list via jQuery.SPservice before.

I did some research to make the parse working first as the following code which works well now.
But it only parse the XML to my own CEWP which is added to the new/edit form, not into the list column that displayed on new/edit form.
Ideally, I should be able to make this work if I know the html tag id of the column.

But after reviewing how the "SPCascadeDropdowns" works to identify the target column, seems like it's not achieved by tag id but something called "StaticName" then I'm here to ask for helps.

**Current Status:**

Here's the image and code for your reference.

[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EngBl.png)

The following codes are running in the CEWP which is added on the top of the new/edit form.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../CEWP%20Libraries/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<b>PR number:</b> PR-<input type="text" id="PRNumber" value="6 digits" maxlength="6" size="3"></input>
<input type="button" value="Load PR" onclick="loadPR($('#PRNumber').val());"></input>
<b>PR Title:</b> <p id="prTitle"></p></br>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
try //Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  }
catch(e)
  {
  try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
    {
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    }
  catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
  }
try 
  {
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load(dname);
  return(xmlDoc);
  }
catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
return(null);
}
function loadPR(PRNumber)
{
    xmlDocPrInfo=loadXMLDoc("http://fakeurl"+PRNumber);

    document.getElementById("prTitle").innerHTML = xmlDocPrInfo.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}
</script>
```

Comment: From my understanding you want to populate fields based off an item already existing in the list? If so, when you go to the list do you see other items that are not yours?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I will edit my problem description to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did some more study these days and the solution is way more easy than I thought with jQuery.(It seems easy if I'm familiar with jQuery, but I'm not :P so this took me a while to get it done.)

But still, there are something tricky to get it works and the first answer from [LZ_MSFT](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/70084/lz-msft) in [this discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248010/sharepoint-single-line-of-text-field-value-using-jquery/248022?newreg=84f771d731634fcfa1bd6a93f4916e18) helps me a lot.

I cannot make this done if I didn't see his answer, because I will get stuck for the "Require Filed" not in the code and have no idea why it's not working when all the sample are nearly the same but all of them won't work. I was testing all the sample from other discussion but no one mentioned this.

The template for you to set the column(field) with jQuery is

```
$("input[title='the display name in the form']").val("the text value you want to set");
```

And if it is a required column(field), it needs to be

```
$("input[title='the display name in the form Require Field']").val("the text value you want to set");
```

Please note that is just the display name, not the FieldInternalName, it won't work, at least in my case, if the **title=** is followed by FieldInternalName in the code. So you will need unique display names in your form if you are going to use this code to make it work, I guess.

Also, in my case, I will need the value comes from the XML, so this is the code in my case to set the value of column(field) in form which comes from the XML.

```
function loadPR(PRNumber)
{
    xmlDocPrInfo=loadXMLDoc("fakeurl"+PRNumber);
    xmlDocSwPrInfo=loadXMLDoc("fakeurl"+PRNumber);


    $("input[title='Title Required Field']").val(xmlDocPrInfo.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    $("input[title='PR Status Required Field']").val(xmlDocPrInfo.getElementsByTagName("State")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    $("input[title='Version Reported Required Field']").val(xmlDocSwPrInfo.getElementsByTagName("VersionReported")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    $("input[title='Version Fixed']").val(xmlDocSwPrInfo.getElementsByTagName("VersionFixed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```